# how to include dbadapter in view/layout in zend framework 2.3?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

i would use my database adapter in my app layout template, but i can't do it! this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getServiceLocator' in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:529 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('getServiceLocat...', true) #1 C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(377): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('getServiceLocat...', NULL) #2 C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(396): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('getServiceLocat...') #3 C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\module\Application in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 529
```

i tried to add directly in my application\view\layout like this:

```
 $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

i tried to add within a Application\Module\dbAdapter like this:

```
    namespace Application\Model;

 class dbAdapter 
 {
     protected $adapter;
     public function getAdapter()
{
   if (!$this->adapter) {
      $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
      $this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
   }
   return $this->adapter;
}
 }
```

and I include it in application\view\layout

```
    use Application\Model\dbAdapter;

  $dbAdapter = new dbAdapter();
  $dbAdapter-> getAdapter();
```

but the error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application\Model\dbAdapter::getServiceLocator() in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Easyanimal\module\Application\src\Application\Model\dbAdapter.php on line 10
```

this is the config\autoload\global.php

```
 return array(
   'db' => array(
      'driver'         => 'Pdo',
      'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2-testdb;host=localhost',
   ),
   'service_manager' => array(
      'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
      ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the adapter from the controller to the view as a parameter ($dbAdapter is your db-adapter instance).

in your controller:

```
$view = new ViewModel(array(
    'dbAdapter' => $dbAdapter,
));

return $view;
```

or alternatively you can also just return an array:

```
return array(
    'dbAdapter' => $dbAdapter,
);
```

in view (layout) you can access the variables like this:

```
<?php $dbAdapter ?>
```

although I don't know why you need the db-adapter in the template.

Comment: i was about to post the same, this is logical as it is specified to certain view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter(); ?>
```